# Validate Dynamic input filed with "formvalidation.io"

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, formvalidation-plugin

I am using Plugin [Form Validation](http://formvalidation.io) to validate the form. And this plugin is working awesome.

 But i am facing issue in validating dynamically generated inputs.

Below code is used to generate input fields dynamically

```
$("#countaccmp").change(function() {
  var selVal = $(this).val();
  $("#textboxDiv").html('');
  if(selVal > 0) {
    for(var i = 1; i<= selVal; i++) {
        $("#textboxDiv").append('<input type="text" name="accmp'+i+'" 
        id="accmp'+i+'" class="form-control " />');
    }
  }       
})
```

I tried validating with plugin as below:

```
$('#form').formValidation({
       //--------- Plugin Validator Method -----------//
})
.on('change', '[name="countaccmp"]', function(e) {
        //---- Wrote validation here, It works(only on change) but form is getting submitted 
               even after error ----//
       $('.dynDiv').each(function(){
          var input = $(this).children('input');
          var dynField = 
           ($(this).find("input[name^='accmp']").attr('name'));

            if(input.val() == '' || input.val() == undefined){
                alert("Error");
                return false;
            }
 })
 .on('success.form.fv', function(e) {
         //---- Wrote validation here, It works but form is getting 
                submitted even after error ----//
          Same Validation As above
  })
```

Please let me know solution.

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag when your question has nothing to do with this plugin.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add your inputs to the plugin in order to be validated.

To do so, use the `addField` method, see bellow:

```
$("#countaccmp").change(function () {
    var selVal = $(this).val();
    $("#textboxDiv").html('');
    if (selVal > 0) {
        for (var i = 1; i <= selVal; i++) {
            var input = ''
                + '<div class="form-group">'
                + '    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="accmp' + i + '">Accmp ' + i + '</label>'
                + '    <div class="col-sm-5">'
                + '        <input type="text" name="accmp' + i + '" id = "accmp' + i + '" class = "form-control " / >'
                + '    </div>'
                + '</div>';
            $("#textboxDiv").append(input);
            $('#defaultForm').formValidation('addField', 'accmp' + i, {
                validators: {
                    // Here, add your field validators.
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

#### Demo:

- http://jsfiddle.net/Arkni/fpps1dqn/

#### References:

- addField documentation: http://formvalidation.io/api/#add-field
- Example using `addField`: http://formvalidation.io/examples/adding-dynamic-field/